# How to plot these signal

Tags: signal-processing, linear-systems

I am very confused when it come to multiplied of function.

Like if it 2rect(t/2)+cos(6πt) I'm okay.

But when it come to something like x(t) = 2rect(t/2)cos(6πt), x(t) = sinc(2t)rect(t/2)

Can anyone show me example how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) looks like this:

[image: rectangular fucntion]

A multiplication of some function $g(x)$ with that function will result in the value 0 where the rectangular function is 0, ${1\over2}g(x)$ at the border of the rectangle and $g(x)$ where the rectangle is 1.

So very basically speaking, applying the rectangle function to some signal function via multiplication means to only look at the signal in a certain range specified by the rectangle. It acts as a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to add some signal processing terminology.

Thus your plots looks like this:

- https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2rect(t%2F2)cos(6%CF%80t)
- https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sinc(2t)rect(t%2F2)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm totally understand when I read your answer. Thanks again ! ;)